# How to set up unit tests for classes in dspace/modules/additions?

Tags: intellij-idea, dspace

I want to set up unit tests for a curation task that i put in `dspace/modules/additions`.
I use intelliJ IDEA and try to configure `sources` and `tests` folders. I wanted to use the following folder structure but could not get the configuration in intelliJ right.

```
 [] DSpace Source Folder
   [] dspace
     [] modules
        [] additions    
           [] src
              [] main
                 [] java
                    […]
              [] test
                 [] java
                    […]
        [] jspui
        [] oai
        [] rdf
        […]
```

Is this structure reasonable?
How can I configure the folders in intelliJ's Project Structure so that it recognises my test folder?

If I try to mark it as "Test Source Folder" in IntelliJ's Project Structure I get the following error message:

> Source root "/.../DSpace6/dspace/modules/additions/src/test" cannot be
>   defined in module "dspace" because it belongs to content of nested
>   module "additions"

Comment: That structure seems right. I think all you need to do is right click the test directory and mark it as "test source root". IntelliJ should figure it out from there. If it doesn't maybe you could elaborate on what you're expecting?

Comment: I updated the question with the missing error message that I get, when trying to mark the folder as "test source"

Comment: Actually it's the java folder under test that should be marked as "test sources root", sorry. But even so I don't know why it would give an error

Comment: It gives the same error if I choose the java folder as "test sources root".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ's `project structure`, I selected the `dspace` module and then, from within this module, chose the `additions` module. This resulted in an error message described in my question.

But the `additions` module also appears as it's own module at the root level of `project structure`. And at this point, I could define the `Test Source Folders` as expected.